# Adding items to a listbox from a crated list

Tags: c#

```
        private void SaveDinosaur_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dino d = new Dino();
            textBoxName.Text = d.name;
            textBoxDiet.Text = d.diet;
            textBoxHeight.Text = Convert.ToString(d.height);
            textBoxAttribute.Text = d.attribute;
            textBoxPower.Text = Convert.ToString(d.power);

            DinoList.Add(d);

        }

        private void listBoxDinoListDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BtnDisplayAllCreated_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Dino d in DinoList)
            {

            }
        }
```

I cant seem to save a users input when I click the SaveDinosaur button, to then allow me to click the display all dinosaurs button, to then show inside of the listbox. I am wondering how I would then add the saved items to a listbox with the foreach statement. And when I try anything else, it says it doesnt work as its being used in the get set method used in another class method.

Images added for explanation:

[UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiz9Y.png)

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNPTR.png)

Comment: Please add additional information, e.g. does an exception occur? How do you add the items to the listbox?

Comment: Possibly because you have the assignments backwards: `textBoxName.Text = d.name;` Puts the d.Name into the textbox.  Since the `d` was just created, I suspect the properties are empty.  That seems to have nothing whatsoever to do with the title though

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain i have swapped them round but nothing is displaying under the textbox?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) in this case, because it would properly update the 'connected' controls.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private List<Dino> _dinoList;
    BindingSource _bindingSource;

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dinoList = new List<Dino>();

        _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        _bindingSource.DataSource = _dinoList;

        lbDinos.DisplayMember = nameof(Dino.Name);
        lbDinos.DataSource = _bindingSource;
    }

    private void btnAddData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dinoList.Add(new Dino(txtDinoName.Text));

        // Reload data
        _bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

        // Select last inserted
        lbDinos.SelectedIndex = (lbDinos.Items.Count - 1);
    }
}

public class Dino
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dino(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AhrenHart I've added the 'Dino' class. It should work with the get and set accessors.